# Want to place a button to close the iFrame, but button click is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, meteor, meteorite

In my meteor based application i am using an I frame to show some contents to the user. It is working properly. But i want to place a close button which unloads the Iframe from the template when clicked.
I tried it as in the code given below by placing a button, but I am unable to get click event on it. means button click is not working. I am working with iframes for the first time.

Is this the right way to unload an iframe? 
If not then how can i unload it, or what is the best way to unload an Iframe?

```
<template name="preview">
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='preview' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
    <button id="close_content_file">Close</button>
        <iframe frameborder="1" src="{{preview_url}}" align="left" width="100%" height="500px" >
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
Template.preview.events({
'click #close_content_file':function(){
    console.log(" previev butoon has been clicked");
    $("#preview").fadeOut();
},

});
```

I placed a `<button></button>` in the div to close or unload the Iframe. but click is not working on that button.If I place the button in the div which is hidden. The button is working there. Iframe is opening on the complete screen. means it over lays the omplete screen as bootstrap modal dialogbox.can i place a button in the Iframe itself? . help will be appreciable

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the binding of event with the button. Use this way.

```
 $("#close_content_file").bind("click", function() {
        //console.log(" previev butoon has been clicked");
        $("#preview").fadeOut();
    });
```

Comment: My problem is button click is not happening. I am clicking the button but the function is not called. I tried it with an Alert and console.log. but function is not called

Comment: button click happen only if it is binded properly with the event. so try to bind this way.

Comment: Okay, let me check and try this. Actually meteor provides its own implementation to detect the clicks and other events. lemme se how can i use jquery function call in Metero

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which JS lib you are using, and also I'm a little confused about the

```
<div style='display:none'>
```

but I make a little modification so it works fine with jQuery , 
here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/QHxac/

Comment: I am using Meteorjs. and I am using that div to hide the content. when a user click on preview button that div starts display and Iframe opened inside the div

Comment: @SajidAhmad sorry, I'm not familiar with Meteorjs, when you execute your js in the browser, is there any exception log in the console? or could u make a similar version on js fiddle, so we can help you out?

Comment: No, there is no exception in log. everything is working fine without any exception or error. just this method is not calling on click. and thanx merlin

Comment: Maybe try jQuery or native JS to bind this click event. This might be my last advice, sorry I couldn't offer u more help:)

Comment: Thanx Merlin for your valuable suggestions. I will try in the way you show me.

Comment: If i place the button in the div which is hidden and unhide the div . the button is orking there. Iframe is opening on the complete screen. means it over lays the omplete screen as bootstrap modal dialogbox.